# How to remove word in the beginning of the string and all after the certain string?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to remove words from the string, for instance:

```
select 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.'
...
```

I want to get the `ipsum dolor sit` - to remove the first word, and all after the "sit"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `sit` fixed, or is it that you want the 2nd, 3rd and 4th words?

Answer (score 2):

Use backreferences for this. First split your string up in 3 groups: (1) what you don't want before your string (2) the actual string (3) whatever comes after your string.

- (1) zero or more characters starting at the beginning for the replace_string: `(^.*)`
- (2) actual string `(ipsum dolor sit)`
- (3) zero or more characters starting after replace_string to the end of the replace_string: `(.*$)`
- (4) replace only with actual string `\2`

```
with test_data (c) as (

select 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.' from dual UNION ALL
select 'ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.' from dual UNION ALL
select 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit' from dual

)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(c,'(^.*)(ipsum dolor sit)(.*$)','\2') from test_data;

ipsum dolor sit
ipsum dolor sit
ipsum dolor sit
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve OP's question and is equivalent to just `select 'ipsum dolor sit'`. As currently worded, OP wants words 2, 3 and `sit` - *no matter what those words are*. eg input of `'foo bar baz sit qux'` should produce `'bar baz sit'`. It is unclear to me if `sit` is fixed or OP just wants words 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Agree - I misread the question. If OP provides more detailed info i'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks Koen but, I agree with @Bohemian

Comment: I want to remove first word from string and all after "sit"

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string functions (which are much faster that regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN sit > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(
              value,
              first_space + 1,
              sit + 3 - first_space
            )
       END AS substring
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, ' ') AS first_space,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(value, ' sit ') > 0
         THEN INSTR(value, ' sit ')
         WHEN value LIKE '% sit'
         THEN LENGTH(value) - 3
         ELSE 0
         END AS sit
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dolor sit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'First situation sitar sit site' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SUBSTRING |
> | --- |
> | ipsum dolor sit |
> | dolor sit |
> | ipsum dolor sit |
> | sit |
> | *null* |
> | situation sitar sit |

---

If you did want to use (slow) regular expressions then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\s((.*?\s)?sit)(\s|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS substr
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs the same.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=234af5512fe2b9732fb7964a8fbd0817)*